# "position in many markets" VS "positions in many markets"

Tags: plural-forms

> 1. It broadens GE’s offering and strengthens the **position** of GE in attractive market segments.
>
> 2.It broadens GE’s offering and strengthens the **positions** of GE in attractive market segments.

Since there are more than one market segments, will it be necesssary to make position plural?

Answer (score 1):

If positions in different markets differ (or may differ), you should use plural **"positions"**. Example:

> "check positions in all markets"

But when a position is the same or similar in all markets, you should use **"position"**. Example:

> "a strong position in all markets"